# Get xpath of div having multiple occurence in page

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am having a weird requirement. I am having a div class named "expandThisSection". And I have

```
<div id=​"requiredAccessoriesContentPlaceHolder" class=​"expandThisSection">​No required accessories are available for this product.​</div>​

<div id=​"requiredAccessoriesContentPlaceHolderMeasurement" class=​"expandThisSection">​&nbsp;​</div>​

<div id=​"optionalAccessoriesContentPlaceHolder" class=​"expandThisSection">​No optional accessories are available for this product.​</div>​

<div id=​"optionalAccessoriesContentPlaceHolderMeasurement" class=​"expandThisSection">​&nbsp;​</div>​

 <div class=​"expandThisSection">​
    <div style=​"width:​95%">​mytext</div>​
    ​<ul class=​"movePos">​…​</ul>​
    <div><b>test</b>​</div>
    ​<div>​<b>abc</b> Get this text</div>
    ​<div id=​"vendLogo">​…​</div>
 </div>

<div class="expandThisSection">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

I want the content of the div that has style of 95% width.That is value I want is "mytext". But I am not able to find out xpath for the same.

Also I want xpath for finding the div content just above div with id=​"vendLogo". That is I want "Get this text".

**NOTE: ITS ASSURED THAT THIS Bold tag WILL CONTAIN "abc"**

How to do it? I am using selenium with Java

Got the first one. Not able to get second one.

Code:

```
List<WebElement> currentSkuDescription = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='expandThisSection']/div"));
          for(WebElement currentItem: currentSkuDescription) {
              WebElement descriptionBlock = currentItem.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style, 'width:95%')]"));
              description= descriptionBlock.getText();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you to search for the `div` by a specific text (in this case 'mytext') this you can use this xpath:

```
"//div[text()[contains(.,'mytext')]]/ancestor::div[@class='expandThisSection']"
```

Or if you want by the styling, the you can use this xpath:

```
"//div[@style='width:95%']/ancestor::div[@class='expandThisSection']"
```

Note that the second xpath will only work where the inline styling is done on the tag.

For the second query, try this xpath:

```
"//div[@id='vendLogo']/preceding-sibling::div[1]"
```

To get the specific text you require, you can do the following:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='vendLogo']/preceding-sibling::div[1]")).getText();
text.replace(div.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText(), "");
```

Comment: Try this `"//div[@id='vendLogo']/preceding-sibling::div[1]"`

Comment: @GitCoder - The xpath which I have provided will solve your issue in one line of code. I'd suggest to use this rather than looping through it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the @class='expandThisSection' because the div you want does not have that class attribute (it's parent does). Also, an exact match may be possible.

> By.xpath("//div[@style='width:95%'] 
>   By.xpath("//div[contains(@style, 'width:95%')]

Either of those should work. If you want to make sure you are grabbing the right one, relative to the parent, use XPath axes...

> //div[contains(@class, 'expandThisSection')]/child::div[contains(@style, 'width:95%')]

Comment: See my code. I handled it :) Help me for second one

Comment: //b[contains(text(),'abc')]/ancestor::div